# xUnit Tests no longer finding tests in VS 2013

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, xunit.net

If this is a duplicate please let me know and I'll promptly close this question out.

I've got a small issue with xUnit in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 (12.0.30723.00). Some time ago, apparently, my tests stopped showing up in the Test Explorer around a recent update to xUnit's test runner.

I have verified the proper extension is installed in Visual Studio (v0.99.8)

I have also verified my project references a supported version of xUnit (1.9.2.1705).
Here is a test I just wrote:

```
using Xunit;
namespace Core.Test
{
    public class CoreTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I Compile the solution, the Test Explorer does not find any tests to run.
My solution is currently set to x86 - DEBUG build. Changing this to x64 or AnyCPU (Debug/Release) does not change this.

Now, if I upgrade xunit from 1.9.2.1705 to xunit 2.0 b4 build 2738, the test runner finds all of my tests just fine.

Does anybody else have the same issue as me and if so how do I resolve it?

Comment: It sounds like you found a solution. Upgrade the test runner.

Comment: @DanielMann: Upgrading the test runner isn't the solution as I'm already on the latest version of the Test Runner, which says supports all versions of xunit v1. I upgraded xunit to v2 which the test runner also supports. I just want to know why v1 suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

To Be Safe:

First, make sure that you're using the package instead of the extension.  Uninstall the extension by going to Tools -> Extensions and Updates then scroll to the bottom and uninstall it.

Now right-click the solution > Manage Nuget Packages For Solution and install the xUnit runners package.

My Suggestion to Solve Your Issue:
If the solution is in the same directory as the project, [this change](https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/commit/fb23aabd8944d3b1e065ebd72aaf294a028da1b0) just fixed a bug with tests not being found.

Otherwise, I've noticed that if you change your Projects directory (Tools > Projects and Solutions > General) to something other than the default (%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects), the issue crops up.  So try resetting your Projects directory to the default.